# How do I generate quasi-random statistical data sets?

Tags: testing, dataset, statistics, data-generation

I'm looking for a tool that will let me generate a data set with certain statistical properties.  For example, suppose I want to generate 1 million integers with x number of outliers for use in testing.

Are there any tools for generating test data sets like this?  I don't necessarily need anything fancy, just some basic functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Math from apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/math/userguide/random.html) has some tools you can use for generating data from simple probability distributions. It is actually pretty easy to [roll your own variant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation) of these generation functions using the random() functionality of whatever system you're using. Assuming random() returns a uniformly distributed random number between 0 and 1 you just pass that through the [inverse cumulative distribution function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) of whatever distribution you need to get the random numbers you need. If you need something very fancy you can use [Markov Chains](http://bryanpendleton.blogspot.com/2009/09/using-markov-chains-for-test-data.html).

Answer (score 3):

The easiest technique, at least the easiest to understand, mathematically, is the [accept-reject algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) algorithm.